# Modal Popup closes when select gridview row / ASP / AJAX / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a Modal Popup that launches from a `LinkButton` inside a `GridView`.
Inside the Modal Popup there are 3 `TextBox` and 3 `GridView`. Users select items from the `GridView` row which are then populated inside the text boxes.

When a users selects a `GridView` row, the modal popup closes. If you open the modal popup again the `TextBox` is populated but I need the modal popup to remain open.

Main Page Gridview

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" CssClass="mGrid" 
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" 
                    HtmlEncode="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Order" HeaderText="Order" 
                    HtmlEncode="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Drinks" HeaderText="Drinks" 
                    HtmlEncode="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" 
                    HtmlEncode="true" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Link" 
                    Visible="false" SelectText="Enroll" />
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" 
                            Text="Add Lunch" OnClick="Edit"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Main Page Modal Popup

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" class="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Header" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Order"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Drinks">
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Comments">
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrder" runat="server" Rows="3" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDrinks" runat="server" Rows="3" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" Rows="3" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Visible="false">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Visible="false">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Order History
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvOrder" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvOrder_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Order" HeaderText="Order" 
                            HtmlEncode="true" />
                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Add To Order" 
                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDrinks" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvDrinks_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Drinks" HeaderText="Drinks" 
                            HtmlEncode="true" />
                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Add To Order" 
                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvComments" runat="server" CssClass="mGrid" 
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" 
                            HeaderText="Comments" 
                            HtmlEncode="true" />
                        <asp:CommandField SelectText="Add To Order" 
                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="popup_Buttons">
                    <asp:Button ID="Okaybtn" runat="server" Text="Done" 
                        OnClick="Save" />
                    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Cancel" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false" 
    PopupControlID="Panel2" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this happens and what I can do to get around it?
Let me know if you need to see some of the codebehind.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but you can call

modalPopupExpander.Show();

Possible way for this is to register to an event of your modal-content page.